# SELECT empty values in snowflake select and count statement

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my first time handling a snowflake table, but I have a difficulty selecting empty values in my SQL query.

This is an example table:

[image]

I am selecting count of customers whom registrations is NOT TRUE. I used this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE Registered != 'TRUE'
```

I got only two customers because of empty (NULL) values, then I tried another query with `NULLIF` to include nulls:

```
SELECT count(NULLIF(Registered,'')) AS TEST FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE Registered != 'TRUE'
```

This also did not include the empty values in the total count!

Comment: finally, Found the solution and got the right count:  `WHERE  (Registered != 'TRUE' OR  Registered IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html) null-safe comparison:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE Registered IS DISTINCT FROM 'TRUE';
```

In this scenario the condition could be part of conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT_IF(Registered IS DISTINCT FROM 'TRUE') AS count_not_true_and_nulls,
   COUNT_IF(Registered != 'TRUE') AS count_not_true_without_nulls
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

Output:

[image]